# Add circle overlay to marker with checkboxes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay

Google Maps API v3

Hey, I want to have atleast 2 checkboxes for my map. When you click the first one a marker drops to the map with a circle overlay around it. And when you check the second box another circle creates with a different radius around the first one, even if the marker has been moved.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a conceptual answer to your conceptual question.  If you want a more specific technical answer, you should point to some live code of your implementation.

You need to use event listeners for the checkboxes (e.g., via jQuery).  You would simply create the marker object and store the marker as a global variable.  Whenever you check the second checkbox, you would use the global variable to access the marker object, get the marker's LatLng, and then add the circle to the map based on the marker's center point (i.e., the LatLng object).  This would work even if the marker position changes.  You could also apply this approach to multiple markers, provided that you store them as objects in a global array that you can then use to reference the marker objects via index.